# .htaccess causing internal redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file which resides in /home/mydir/foo/sites/bar:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/mydir/foo/sites/bar/apache/$1 [QSA,L]
```

and of course, I have the following directory w/ an index.php file:

```
ls -l /home/mydir/foo/sites/home/mydir/foo/sites/bar/apache/
index.php
```

Basically, my problem is I need to redirect all traffic to "/home/mydir/foo/sites/bar/apache/", but I keep seeing

```
/home/mydir/foo/sites/bar/home/mydir/foo/sites/bar....
```

... in my error logs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `/home/mydir/foo/sites/bar` directory?

Comment: There should not be anything in the bar directory.  I just need all traffic redirected to /home/mydir/foo/sites/apache/

Comment: is there an .htaccess file inside /home/mydir/foo/sites/apache/ as well?

Comment: No, there is no .htaccess in /home/mydir/foo/sites/bar

Comment: You wrote in question: `I have the following .htaccess file which resides in /home/mydir/foo/sites/bar:` then in comments you wrote: `No, there is no .htaccess in /home/mydir/foo/sites/bar`. Which one is correct statement? What URL are you entering in browser and what is your DocumentRoot set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  The issue is with the endpoint.  I changed it to the following:

```
apache/index.php
```

All is good now.